# Page not found when following wagtail tutorial adding tags

Tags: django, http-status-code-404, wagtail

I wanted to add tags to posts in the quickstart Wagtail blog by following the [(Wagtail tutorial)](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#tag-posts).  When I clicked the "foood" tag that I added to one of my posts, I ran into a **Page not found (404) error**.  Check out the screenshot below [image: Page not found debug output]

Here is my **class BlogTagIndexPage(Page)** in **blog/models.py**

```
# Add BlogTagIndexPage
class BlogTagIndexPage(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):

        # Filter by tag
        tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)

        # Update template context
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context
```

and my **blog_tag_index_page.html** in **blog/templates/blog/**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}

    {% if request.GET.tag %}
        <h4>Showing pages tagged "{{ request.GET.tag }}"</h4>
    {% endif %}
        
    {% for blogpage in blogpages %}

          <p>
              <strong><a href="{% pageurl blogpage %}">{{ blogpage.title }}</a></strong><br />
              <small>Revised: {{ blogpage.latest_revision_created_at }}</small><br />
          </p> 

    {% empty %}
        No pages found with that tag.
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing?

This is my **models.py**.  Class BlogPage is included:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField
# add tags to allow users to view tagged content
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase


# add wagtail classes and methods
from wagtail.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel
from wagtail.search import index

# add snippets
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

# Add BlogTagIndexPage
class BlogTagIndexPage(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):

        # Filter by tag
        tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)

        # Update template context
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context

class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro')
    ]

    # add the get_context method:
    def get_context(self, request):
        # Update context to include only published posts, ordered by reverse-chron
        context = super().get_context(request)
        blogpages = self.get_children().live().order_by('-first_published_at')
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context


class BlogPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'BlogPage',
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    # the main_image method:
    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    # Add authors:
    authors = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.Author', blank=True)

    # Add tags:
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [

        # Add MultiFieldPanel including date panel, authors panel
            MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('date'),
            FieldPanel('authors', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
             # Add field for tags:
            FieldPanel('tags'),
        ], heading="Blog information"),

        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body'),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
    ]

class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]

@register_snippet
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('author_image'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Authors'
```

This is my **blog_page.html** template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-blogpage{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p class="meta">{{ page.date }}</p>

        <!-- Add authors multi-field panel to blog page template: -->
    {% with authors=page.authors.all %}
        {% if authors %}
            <h3>Posted by:</h3>
            <ul>
                {% for author in authors %}
                    <li style="display: inline">
                        {% image author.author_image fill-40x60 style="vertical-align: middle" %}
                        {{ author.name }}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}


    <div class="intro">{{ page.intro }}</div>

    {{ page.body|richtext }}

        <!-- image gallery -->
    {% for item in page.gallery_images.all %}
        <div style="float: inline-start; margin: 10px">
            {% image item.image fill-320x240 %}
            <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <p><a href="{{ page.get_parent.url }}">Return to blog</a></p>

    <!-- Add this: -->
    {% with tags=page.tags.all %}
        {% if tags %}
            <div class="tags">
                <h3>Tags</h3>
                {% for tag in tags %}
                    <a href="{% slugurl 'tags' %}?tag={{ tag }}"><button type="button">{{ tag }}</button></a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Looking at the URL in the error message, it seems likely that you followed a link from `blog/first-blog-post/` that had a URL of `None` instead of the correct URL. Can you share the model and template for BlogPage?

Comment: It looks like the `{% slugurl 'tags' %}` tag is returning None. Did you create an instance of BlogTagIndexPage and give it the slug "tags" as instructed? If so, are you able to view that page through the "View live" link in the Wagtail admin?

Answer (score 0):

Just forgot to create a **BlogTagIndexPage** and give it the slug "tags" on the Promote tab.  Exact instructions from [wagtail tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#tag-posts) are shown below.  I bolded the relevant parts of the instructions.  Thanks to Gasman for pointing that out.

> After migrating the new changes, **create a new BlogTagIndexPage in the
> admin interface.** To create the BlogTagIndexPage, follow the same
> process you followed in creating the BlogIndexPage and **give it the
> slug “tags” on the Promote tab.** This means the BlogTagIndexPage is a
> child of the home page and parallel to Our Blog in the admin
> interface.